# XAMPP setup to use name instead of IP address

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, host

I have an internal network for our company and in one of the server I have XAMPP/Apache setup and have my own website.

I access that page from a browser anywhere within a network by entering the following address:

`http://10.10.239.306/MyPage/testpage.php`

I am trying to change so that instead of the IP (which is hard to remember) the user can enter, say for example:

`http://hweb/MyPage/testpage.php`

I followed the online instruction and did the following update on the server hosting the pages:

in the `C:\Windows\system32\driver\etc\host` file I added:

`127.0.0.1  hweb`

in the `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hweb
    ServerAlias myname
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/MyPage
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter `http://hweb/MyPage/testpage.php` in my browser, I get a `Internet Name Resolution Error (dns_server_failure)` error

I did restart the Apache server twice.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: 10.10.239.306 hweb >> [ /etc/hosts || C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ]

Comment: I edited that on the machine that is hosting the XAMPP server.

Comment: IP resolving actually requires this to be either done by a intranet router (like in Google HQ — they're using `go` [ i.e. http://go/ethics ] as their internal namespace) or on the client-machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Internet Name Resolution` Indicates that your browser does not know the IP of `hweb`. I.e. you did not edit the `hosts` file on the client machine (the one which tries to access)

Please verify you have `10.10.239.306 hweb` in `C:\Windows\system32\driver\etc\host` on **Client** machine.

Comment: So each client machine needs to have that in order to be able to access it? What if I have over 1000 machines? that seems kind of redundant.

Comment: That is what DNS servers are for. But, that is more complicated than a hosts file. If your company does not use local DNS server, you have to register a domain (.com costs around $10 a year), if you have local DNS server, then you can add records there.

Comment: We have our internal intranet which can be accessed by `http://mysite` so I guess all the PC has the IP address on each client machine?

Comment: Then you are most likely having local DNS. Find the owner and ask him to add your site :)

Answer (score 1):

try to change the **listen** 
127.0.0.1 hweb, 
check following link;
http://sustainablewebdesign.com/book/resources/xampp/

Comment: I am trying to access the page outside of the server itself. Do I have to edit anything on the client machine?

Comment: change '<VirtualHost ' correct ip address with the correct port, then change the server name as well as Alias name to correct name